# Migration from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.0 + VirtueMart

Tags: joomla, upgrade, virtuemart

I have an e-shop in Joomla 1.5 + VirtueMart1. I wanto to migrate it on Joomla 3.0 + VirtueMart2. Are there any suggestions of any kind on any tutorials about the whole procedure? Or maybe there are some key factors that I should give particular attention to? I have found guides and other staff, but I want to be sure before I start this.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: I don't beleive VirtuMart is compatible with Joomla 3.x. If you want to update your Joomla site, you will need to update to Joomla 2.5 as VirtueMart is compatible with this

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla Update from 1.5 to 3.x is not a wise choice now bcoz, most of the extensions not yet ready for [joomla3.x](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_upgrade_from_Joomla!_1.5_to_3.x?) (Virtuemart).

So it better to update to Joomla 2.5 then a stable release from Joomla3.5 will shortly comes. Then you can update it.

for updating Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 this [plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609)  will help.

Also for updating Vm 1.1.x to Vm2.x help is [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/virtuemart-11-to-version-2/)

**Updates**

Now VM3.x is available for Joomla 3.X check [here](http://virtuemart.net/download)